# Rage graphic lag after half hour of playing (caused by input)

Tags: technical-issues, rage

I have a problem with Rage game. Game runs at 60 FPS with no problems. I have no graphic issues.

After around half hour of playing graphics starts to lag, it looks like graphic stuttering.
The thing is it has nothing to do with graphic just with input, when I don't touch any of the controls the lagging stops. But in moment I touch keyboard or mouse lagging is back again.

I have G13 controller but disconnecting it and turning of it's program does not resolve this issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm really wondering if it is caused by input? Because when you move the game starts to render again causing the lag... i'm pretty sure it is your 3D card. I would check both these questions out and maybe see if one fixes your problem : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34196/what-can-i-do-to-improve-the-very-poor-performance-of-rage/ and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32060/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-texture-popping-in-rage/

Comment: I't is hard to explain it but I'm more than 100% sure that's not a graphic issue. For example you can just start shooting and nothing else, looking in an empty space and it will lag. GPU and graphic card memory does not change at all.

Comment: Well that is what i'm trying to prove,everything that you do with either your keyboard or mouse forces the game to think and render. Shoot = flashes, bullet holes... , we are talking about rage here on pc, which is a real crappy port and even on consoles it had trouble.

Comment: Sounds like your graphics card or CPU can't keep up once they get too warm.  If the graphics start corrupting, it's almost guaranteed the video card.  It could also be the hard drive that it's installed on.  If the system can't pull data fast enough to keep up, that could be causing this stuttering.

Comment: as @fbueckert pointed out more often than not delayed stuttering is caused by either a overheating GPU/CPU or Memory Leaks. I trust id software has good enough coders to not have memory leaks. So I would suspect an overheating component.

Comment: I have EVGA precision installed with fan curve set so it will speed up all fans on GPU twice as fast as temperature will rise. Hard drive is SSD OCZ vertex 3 max IOPS. Can I somehow turn the processor fan speed up?

Comment: Perhaps we can narrow down the issue.  Does this happen only in Rage?  Or does it happen to any game after about half an hour or so?

Comment: I have other problems with different games, but they something totally different. Battlefield 3 for example can just crash a whole PC, but it is happening on the latest maps only, an Skyrim has a similar issue, but I can see it's related to graphic card. The other thing is I don't have problems like that with other new games, eg. Bioshock Infinite, Remember me, Borderlands 2. BTW graphic card is Asus GTX 570 direct CU II.

Comment: That's strange.  Your symptoms are pointing to a failing video card, but if that was the case, it should be doing it to all those games.  Are they all installed on the same hard drive?

Comment: I have two hard drives, SSD and HDD, different games on different hard drive. Battlefield 3 works from SSD. Yesterday I was testing Skyrim and I can see if the lagging occurs graphic card memory goes to 99% so maybe settings are to high for my GPU. But Rage has nothing like that going on.

Comment: About the only thing I can suggest at this point is to see if you can swap out the video card and see what happens.  That's what the symptoms are pointing to, however inconsistently.